# Git: How to retrieve all commits from all branches without notes?

Tags: git

I need to retrieve all commits from all branches. I retrieve them using command:

```
git log --pretty="%H %f" --all
```

But in this case Git returns me all commits with notes, if such exist. I tried to use something like the following:

```
 git log --pretty="%H %f" --all --no-notes
```

It looks like the command "--all" overrides "--no-notes" and nothing will happen.

Please advise how can I retrieve all commits from all branches without notes?

P.S. Yes, I could execute "git notes", parse them and then subtract from "git log --all", but it seems to me there should be a much easier solution for such a trivial situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `--all` overrides `--no-notes`. So you may want to split `--all` to include only refs you want. If you just want to show all the branches:

```
git log --pretty="%H %f" --no-notes --branches
```

or if you want more:

```
git log --pretty="%H %f" --no-notes --branches --tags --remote
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but instead of `--all`, you could do this:

```
git log --pretty="%H %f" `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" | grep -v refs/notes`
```

Or in some other way enumerate just the refs you want to log, which can be understandably tedious if you have many branches/tags...