# How to retrieve all history from all branches using jgit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

Looks like it is possible to see all history from git repository using "git log" command.
[Git: How to retrieve all commits from all branches without notes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842350/git-how-to-retrieve-all-commits-from-all-branches-without-notes)

How to achieve the same result using jgit?

Answer (score 0):

Like this for example:

```
...
Git git = new Git(repository);
Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();
for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
    ...
}
```